# ¿Como importo librería conio2 si programo en Sublime Text 3?

Tags: c++, c, sublimetext3

Estoy trabajando en Sublime Text 3 programando en lenguaje C y C++, necesito utilizar la librería conio2 para mi proyecto, pero en la red solo encuentro la manera de utilizarla en Dev-C++ u otros IDE's, necesito la manera de utilizarla con mi editor de texto.

Mi compilador es GCC y trabajo sobre Windows 10, arquitectura de 32 bits. Gracias.

Comment: `conio` no es una cabecera estándar de C o C++, si la necesitas deberá proveerla el sistema operativo o el compilador que estés usando.

Comment: mira esto: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24225343/how-to-compile-and-run-c-in-sublime-text-3